# After package installation, why Emacs kept retrieving an error message on "Creating directory: Operation not supported" subsequent to normal behavior?

Tags: osx, use-package, linux, install, directory

I was using this [init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/92914433253797efe0b939844c4d8bd94f61d8e5/.emacs.d/init.el) on a NixOS machine.

It is important to note that parts of the file were written with [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) and other parts were a legacy from the classic imperative installation of packages: `M-x`, `package-install`, and tweaks on hooks and variables.

This weekend I started a new set-up in a **new** Macbook Air M1 for professional reasons. I must highlight that I am new to Mac.

As I was trying to make myself at home with Emacs in MacOS, I started to copy small snippets of my old config file and slightly migrate them to mac. As the process was going, I decided to use the opportunity to "code review" my own init file - especially to make it more **declarative** via `use-package`. The expectation was to make it more reproducible for future occasions.

Sometimes, especially after creating a declaration of a package not yet installed, there was a weird thing happening. I would receive the following messages on the mini-buffer area:

[image]

[image]

The funniest point was that after quitting (`C-x C-c`) and re-starting Emacs, **things worked fine (as expected)** and the error message would disappear!

And this problem/phenomenon happened multiple times. This is the [new config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el). See [the diff](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/commit/99a90f0f5e113f10056675dfa383cab34d21177d).

Why did this happen? Is the problem related to some specific code snippet? Maybe a reference to a path? Is it related to MacOS?

Now that things work fine and the message is gone, is it possible to reproduce it without installing something new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security concern, Apple re-designed the file system beginning with
High-Sierra version - see [this](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/seca6147599e/web)
or a little bit more detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) - so in your settings you have an absolute path starting with the forbidden `System....` and you must replace it with the permitted `Users/yourname/.emacs.d` or whatever you need.

As for errors in warnings window you see - just do `package-refresh-contents`and try again to install
the package you need.

Comment: Thanks, how exactly can I replace it? Could you give more instructions? Or a recommended material?

Comment: Your ```locate-user-emacs-file``` should be ```"/Users/pedro/.emacs.d/custom-vars.el"``` - if it works for you in another hidden folder ```.dotfiles``` then ok, although Emacs recommend some special paths - see/search ```C-h I ``` and choose the node Emacs and search for initialisation files/paths (not easy to write exactly where it is).

Answer (score 1):

Ian's and Pedro's propositions seem to do the job, but, IMHO, it's very strange to put this in your init file:

```
(setq custom-file (locate-user-emacs-file "/home/pedro/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/custom-vars.el"))
```

since `locate-user-emacs-file` is supposed to take as argument a **file name**, not a file path, and has a (not so simple) strategy to find it in the `user-emacs-directory` (cf. "files.el").

I would rather adapt the `user-emacs-directory` to the current environment.

Note that the following code could be the same on a macos- or on a linux-based machine.

Since, by default, `user-emacs-directory` contains `"~/.emacs.d"`, I would change it like this:

```
(when (file-directory-p "~/.dotfiles")
  (setq user-emacs-directory "~/.dotfiles/.emacs.d"))
```

And then, you could change the name of your custom file like this:

```
(setq custom-file (locate-user-emacs-file "custom-vars.el"))
```

Note that, IMHO, the test with `file-directory-p` is more robust than the test of the `system-configuration`:

```
(setq user-emacs-directory
  (cond
   ((string-match "apple" system-configuration)
    "~/.emacs.d")
   ((string-match "NixOS or whatever ???" system-configuration)
    "~/.dotfiles/.emacs.d")
   (t "~/.emacs.d")))
```

since a macos computer could actually have a `"~/.dotfiles"` directory (as a matter of fact, my macs have had a `"~/DOT_DIRS"` directory since a few decades!)

Answer (score 0):

@[Ian](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12077/ian) was right.

Just to make it even easier for other people to understand it I will post another answer.

This problem originated from the process of bringing an Emacs init file from an old machine (running Linux-based NixOS and with `.dotfiles` being used) to a new macOS machine (which does not use `.dotfiles` on the file hierarchy).

Thus, changing my init file from:

```lisp
(setq custom-file (locate-user-emacs-file "/home/pedro/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/custom-vars.el"))
```

To:

```lisp
(setq custom-file (locate-user-emacs-file "/Users/pedro/.emacs.d/custom-vars.el"))
```

Solved the problem on the new macOS machine.

Also, I tweaked the config file to include comments about the problem:

```lisp
;; Avoid custom variables from Emacs, since this is a handcrafted file
;; Move them to a different file. There is macOS and a nixOS version
;; macOS
(setq custom-file (locate-user-emacs-file "/Users/pedro/.emacs.d/custom-vars.el")) 
;; nixOS config
;;(setq custom-file (locate-user-emacs-file "/home/pedro/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/custom-vars.el"))

(load custom-file 'noerror 'nomessage)
```